# Variable not defined / function not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a CPS test for fun but I ran into a problem:
I defined a function at the beginning of the code and than I defined a tkinter button which has this function as command and the button should disappear in this function. When I do it like this it says that the variable of the button isn't defined yet but when I defined it vice versa so first the button and then the function it says that the function is not defined yet.

Can anyone help me?
(Sorry for my bad English)

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CPS test")
root.geometry("1000x1000")
root.configure(bg='white')



    

def getstring():
    duration = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0)
    entry.place_forget()
    okbutton.place_forget

lab1 = tk.Label(text = "How long should the CPS test last? 2,5 or 10 seconds?(Answer with 2,5,10)", font = "Ariel 20", bg = "#FFFFFF")
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Click me!", font = "Ariel 50", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000")
entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('Arieal 20'), bd = 2)
okbutton = tk.Button(root, text = "OK", font = "Ariel 20", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", bd = 2, command = getstring())




lab1.place(x = 45,y = 250)
entry.place(x = 344, y = 350)
entry.insert(0, "Enter your answer here!")
okbutton.place(x = 465, y = 400)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command = getstring()` should be `command = getstring`. You don't want to call the function when creating the button, it should be called when the button is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

I think the error is on the button name.

```
def getstring():
   duration = entry.get()
   entry.delete(0)
   entry.place_forget()
   button.place_forget
```

Just replace "okbutton" by "button" and it should work.

Else just declared the "okbutton" before the function

Comment: The other comment already solved my problem but still thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).